# How to get a key/value pair on a sibling object in a JSON array conditionally

Tags: json, jq

I'm interacting with an API that returns an array of objects related to a product in JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "type": "category",
    "name": "food"
  },
  {
    "type": "category",
    "name": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "type": "barcode",
    "name": "123456"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to use `jq` tool on `bash` in the shortest and tidiest form, to check if a product has a barcode and it's categorized as food. In other words, check if an object with `type=barcode` exists in the array, then check if there is an object with `type=category` together with `name=food`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @0stone0 Just a `true/false` to use in the `if` statement of bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This outputs `true` or `false` based on your requirements:

```
any(.type=="barcode") and any(.type=="category" and .name=="food")
```

`jq -e` will set the exit code of the program accordingly:

```
if jq -e '...'; then
  ...
fi
```

Without `-e`:

```
if test "$(jq '...')" = true; then
  ...
fi
```

---

And not necessarily shorter or tidier, but semantically easier to follow:

```
group_by(.type)
| map({
    key: first.type,
    value: map(.name)
})
| from_entries
| .category as $cat
| .barcode and ("food"|IN($cat[]))
```

This first builds an intermediate object of the form:

```
{
  "barcode": [
    "123456"
  ],
  "category": [
    "food",
    "fruit"
  ]
}
```

Which you can then query, e.g. does it have a barcode and is "food" one of the categories.